# Scaling UIViewController and children to fit iPad or iPhone screens

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, scale

I am developing a game for the app store and have been using Sprite Kit.  In Sprite Kit to have the game work on both the iPhone and the iPad I set the SKScene's scaleMode=SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill and made the screen proportions so it would fit the iPhone 4&5 screens as well as the iPad and this has worked well.  Now I am building the menus for the app, but I am not using Sprite Kit for this.  Instead I am using Collection Views, Buttons, images, etc.  I am not seeing a similar property to scale the view to a certain size depending on what device I am on. Since I am using images for all of my buttons, ideally just proportionately scaling everything would be the simplest way to achieve what I am looking for.  Am I missing something as far as how best to proceed with this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing Auto Layout. It is the feature specifically designed for this very purpose, i.e. to change sizes and distances of interface objects in response to the fact that the screen is a different size.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

However, for a size difference as great as the iPad vs. the iPhone, if you have a universal app, it sometimes makes sense to design two different interfaces. It is easy to set up the Info.plist or your initial code to load the correct interface depending on which device type this turns out to be at runtime. In fact, if you start by making a Universal app, the project will simply come with two storyboards, one for iPhone and one for iPad, which are loaded automatically.

Another option (which didn't occur to me at first because I don't write these kinds of game) is to scale a superview by applying a view transform (i.e. set its `transform` to a scale transform). That scales the view's coordinate system, so all its subviews will change to match, just like a drawing.

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with auto layout, but I was hoping to avoid having to set the scaling on every single control.  Plus its not just the size I am looking to change, since many of these will be images I want the images to scale as well.  The idea here is to avoid having to have two separate interfaces because they will look identical in the end.  If you look at most games, the menus are usually just scaled down, but I'm not sure the easiest way to do that.

Comment: If the menus are just a drawing, then when you scale it, the whole thing scales. Or you can scale a whole interface by applying a scale transform; I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Have not coded it yet,but your suggestion to use the scale transform looks like it will do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll be interested to know what you ultimately wind up doing...!